# Non-continuous Slider label values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I'm using a [Slider](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider) in a pyplot window and interpretting its top 1% of values (`slider.val > max_val * 0.99`) as infinity.

Is there a way to show this in the slider's label? I mean the right one, showing the value.
The closest one is `valfmt`, but it cannot do that much afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overwrote the `Slider._format` method and added the "infinity" check.

```
class Inf_Slider(mpl.widgets.Slider):
    """ Right label (value) reads "inf", if above the threshold. """

    def __init__(self, *args, inf_threshold, **kwargs):
        self.inf_threshold = inf_threshold
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_inf(self, val):
        """ For outside of the slider treshold check. """
        if val >= self.inf_threshold:
            return True
        return False

    def _format(self, val):
        if self.is_inf(val):
            return 'inf'
        return super()._format(val)
```

I've also tried changing directly `slider.val` to `numpy.inf`, but `super()._format` method doesn't cast it properly.